# How to enable swap/delay/kws apo for sysvad or other real microphone

Tags: windows, audio, driver

Below is Microsoft's official project to demo how to make audio driver.
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/audio/sysvad

After making build, 3 APO dll files are generated. And those inf files contain the installation steps for them.
But I tested and found that those apo effects do not take effect at all.
**My test method is:**
I empty all the codes of `APOProcess()` in those 3 APO and found that audio recorded is not influenced.

**Question 1：**
My understanding is that these APO dlls must be invoked by some programs and then we could have sound effects. While sysvad does not provide such programs.
Am I right？

**Question 2：**
I want to know how do those APO codes interact with sysvad microphone driver? By code, or by some id in the inf file?

**Question 3:**
Furthermore, if I want to reuse the APO codes for other microphone device driver, is it possible and how to modify them? E.g. for my realtek device driver which I have no source code.

Thanks!